# Can I begin sending a web response before it is complete using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

The first portion of my response is static, I would like to go head and send that portion of the page and send the rest after it has been compiled. Is this even possible using node.js?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233562/node-js-chunked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  You can do whatever you want.

[Just `.write()` your data to the response object](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding).  It won't disconnect until you do a `.end()`.  As a bonus, Node will set up chunked encoding for you automatically.  There is nothing more you have to do.