# Download a file from a Http NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a nodejs application in which I have a http server who responds to incoming POST commands. I do need to return an entire binary file. I can do it by using

```
response.end(file, 'binary); // where 'file' is the entire byte array
```

but I don't want to store the whole file in memory, I do want to send it **by chunks**. Is there any other way for doing this? I have googled without success.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use response.write(...) to send chunks. See here: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding

Also, some additonal help in sending chunked responses can be found here:
[Node.js: chunked transfer encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233562/node-js-chunked-transfer-encoding)