# Can I render text/plain content as it arrives?

Tags: http, browser, chunked-encoding

I have an server that delivers data that it processes over about 15 seconds. The headers are as follows:

```
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

With telnet I can confirm that data is sent continuously over 15 seconds. In a browser the whole page hangs until the entire request is received, and then it renders all at once.

Occasionally on longer requests it hangs for a while and then starts streaming data to the screen as it arrives, but I have not deduced the threshold where that happens.

Is there some header or other magic I can send to make the browser render the content as soon as it is availible?

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9751949/17373

Comment: Might not work with text/plain according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233562/node-js-chunked-transfer-encoding#comment17496397_11210088

Comment: yeah, thinking ajax and handling the events directly might work, but not such a big deal really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11210088/17373) you might be able to get it to work by using text/html as the content type (still need the charset=UTF-8 part too) or adding `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` to work around a [webkit bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156023)

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I also have to inject a `<pre>` at the beginning of my stream to make it render like text/plain.

Comment: Works fine with just the "X-Content-Type-Options", for text stream.